# How to access variable in multiple functions of class in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access a variable from one function to another in PHP laravel controller. And I'm unable to do that

```
 class PaymentController extends Controllers
    {
        public function myfatoorah_checkout(Request $request)
        {
            ...

            $invoiceId = $data->InvoiceId;
            $paymentLink = $data->PaymentURL;

            return redirect($paymentLink);
        }

        public function myfatoorah_callback(Request $request)
        {
            // Access $invoiceId here;
            // But I can not access it even after using it as a global variable. it still gives an undefined index error.
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you are describing it, that can't be possible, PHP does not share a state between requests.

Comment: not only that but there is no shared scope between functions/methods

Comment: You could store the value in a class property instead of a local scoped variable. Then you will be able to read that variable from all the methods in the class. Btw, `$invoiceId` will be null since you're reading it from `$data`, which will be undefined at that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PaymentController extends Controllers
{
    public $invoiceId;
    public function myfatoorah_checkout(Request $request)
    {
        ...

        $this->invoiceId = $data->InvoiceId;
        $paymentLink = $data->PaymentURL;

        return redirect($paymentLink);
    }

    public function myfatoorah_callback(Request $request)
    {
        // Access $this->invoiceId here;
    }
}
```

You can access public variable across methods in your class.